# Regarding MySQL Entries [SAAS structure]

Tags: mysql

I'm currently in the process of creating a SAAS structured website. My question is, is it best to have each users entries all in one table identified by a certain identifier? Or is it better to create a new mysql database for each user?

For example, if I have 1M+ entries in the single database, what is the query return time roughly?

What are the advantages and the disadvantages of both?

Answer (score 0):

You usually only have **one** database which contains all of your tables. If you would have a database or table for each user, you would have to create them for each user independently, which is much harder to do than inserting a new entry and doesn't bring any advantages with it.

One of your tables would then be for all users. Databases are made for large amounts of data, so your **queries will be fast** (way under one second) even if you have a million entrys or more. But the speed heavily depends on the complexity of the query you are excecuting and the indices of the table.

Your *'users'* table would then have fields like *'ID'*, *'accountName'*, *'password'*, etc. (please keep in mind that you should **always** encrypt passwords before storing them)

If you have data which requires n fields you create a new table. For example 'shopping cart items' and link it to your *'users'* table with a forign key *'userID'*.

You might want to look into "primary keys", "forign keys", "indices" and "relations".

Hope this helps. *-Minding*